# Mismatch in I/O (JAVA) int/String

Tags: java, string, if-statement, while-loop, int

I have to write a program where the user write the price of an item and, when the users press ctrld the program will print the  lower price (without the name of the item).
The program doesn't print anythink or mismatch. What can i do?

This is the error. How can i modify the code so that a String can be read?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at StampaMinimoParola.main(StampaMinimoParola.java:12)
```

This should be the output:

INPUT

```
apples 10
pears 20
grapes 5
```

OUTPUT

```
5
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StampaMinimoParola {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
        String name="";
        int lower=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int price;

        while (s.hasNext()) { //start of the while loop
            name=s.nextLine(); //name of the article
            price=s.nextInt();//price of the article

            if (price<lower) {
                System.out.println(price);

            }
            //end of while cycle
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the output and how do you need to achieve the result ?

Comment: Or there is no output or it appears:                                              
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at StampaMinimoParola.main(StampaMinimoParola.java:11)

Comment: Input mismatch is usually happened when you expect an integer and you pass it as string

Comment: Before i have to enter a String and then an integer... What should i do?

Comment: your code should read a full line string and then the second line should be read as integer and the other thing is your ode will not be executed unless if do you provide some inputs before the while loop

Comment: Where should i put the input before the while loop?

Comment: Nobody who can help me and can correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just change s.nextLine() to s.next()

nextLine() eats the whole line, so when you try nextInt() you are already at pears